# Prevent an index from allocating multiple primaries to same node

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a 3 nodes cluster and an index made up of 3 primaries. When allocating these shards, I would like each one of them to be assigned to a different node, so each node holds exactly one primary shard of my index.

Is there any way I can enforce this behaviour?

For information, I need this because I'm bulk indexing my data and each one of my primaries fill up to 60% of my available disk space (on each node). So if to primaries get allocated to the same node, it ends up filling up all the available disk space and the node eventually goes down.

**Update to VAL answer:**

I can't actually use the first setting because I do run with replicas. As I specified, one primary shard takes 60% of the **AVAILABLE** disk space. But once indexing of primaries is complete, I can free up space by removing older data, only then I have enough disk space to turn on replicas.

Sorry if I'm wrong but I think you actually meant the `cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high` setting judging by the description you made? It may actually be a good solution but the documentation doesn't describe the process clear enough.  What happens if I am in the process of bulk indexing both my primaries on the same node and the 85% threshold is reached? Will Elasticsearch reallocate one of the primaries right away and continue the bulk indexing on the other node or will it wait for the bulk of both primaries to complete before trying to reallocate one of them to another node? If the second option is correct, then it won't work because my disk space will already reach 100% by the time both primaries are indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since your primary shard takes 60% of the disk space, I assume you're running without replicas.

In this case, you can set the [`cluster.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node` cluster setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/allocation-total-shards.html#cluster-total-shards-per-node) to 1:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.total_shards_per_node" : 1
  }
}
```

However, even if for whatever reason two of your primary shards were allocated to the same node, once those primaries are loaded in such a way that 85% of the node disk space is taken, one of the primary would get allocated away to another node by virtue of the [`cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/modules-cluster.html#disk-based-shard-allocation)

Comment: I had to update my post to answer you because there wasn't enough characters. Please have a look.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the precisions. The first setting will work if you turn on replicas **only after** the bulk upload is finished and if you increase the setting to 2. Regarding the high watermark, once it's reached ES will reallocate the primary shard **right away** and will not wait for the bulk to finish.